# How to convert an integer array to a matrix in c#

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I have an integer array named `resp` I want to rewrite/convert it as/to a `row matrix` with name `resp`.

```
int[] resp= {1, 0, 1, 0};
```

I am using the [Mathnet.Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) library.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the definition of the array `resp`? You've provided literally none of the information anyone would need to give you an applicable answer.

Comment: That already looks like a row matrix (row vector?) of `[1, 0, 1, 0]`. What is your intended output?

Comment: output will be same as [1, 0, 1, 0]; only the object type should change.

Comment: Okay, so what type are what wanting to convert it to? As far as I know, .NET doesn't have a specific type to represent a row vector, but an array as you have now is a reasonable approximation. Are you using a library that you've not included information about in your question?

Comment: I want to convert it to a matrix.
Libraries which I am using

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization;
using MathNet.Numerics.Optimization;

Comment: .NET does not have a built-in representation of a general purpose matrix.

Comment: I've edited in the critical minimum information necessary for anyone to give you a reasonable answer for your question. In the future, please do your best to include this information in your question's first iteration. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Mathnet, you are not able to initialize an array of integers. As it is, there's in limited support available for this. If you tried, you would get this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer 
for 'MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1' threw an exception. ---> 
System.NotSupportedException: Matrices and vectors of type 'Int32' 
are not supported. Only Double, Single, Complex or Complex32 are supported at this point.
```

You can initialize a vector with similar values (with doubles) like this:

```
var resp = new [] {1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};
var V = Vector<double>.Build;
var rowVector = V.DenseOfArray(resp);
```

In order to build a matrix, you would need a multi-dimensional array.